# A value for the logo field is required - in Article->publisher

Tags: schema.org

I was trying to make an article but I was getting the "A value for the logo field is required"

It is not clear in the docs how this should look like.
Also the examples in the docs are failing the validations in
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[Google's look at the logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)**:

> **logo** URL URL of a logo that is representative of the organization.
> Additional image guidelines: The image must be 112x112px, at minimum.
> The image URL must be crawlable and indexable. The image must be in
> .jpg, .png, .gif, .svg, or .webp format.

There is also an example here:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>About Us</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.example.com",
      "logo": "http://www.example.com/images/logo.png"
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check out **[Google's guide for structured data type Articles](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article)**:

> AMP logo guidelines Note: These logo guidelines apply to the Article
> structured data placed on individual AMP pages. For guidelines about
> the Logo markup that apply to the actual logo of a site, see the Logo
> markup documentation. The following guidelines apply to logos for all
> AMP pages, including AMP stories. The file format must be supported by
> Google Images. Don't use animation. The graphic part of the logo
> should be legible on the background color. The following guidelines
> apply to logos used for general AMP pages, not AMP stories. There are
> different logo requirements for AMP stories. The logo must be a
> rectangle, not a square. The logo should fit in a 60x600px rectangle,
> and either be exactly 60px high (preferred), or exactly 600px wide.
> For example, 450x45px would not be acceptable, even though it fits
> within the 600x60px rectangle. Example of a logo Publishers should use
> only one logo per brand that is consistent across general AMP pages.
> Use full wordmark or full logo; not an icon. The text in word-based
> logos should be at most 48px tall and centered vertically within the
> 60px image height. Add additional space to pad the height to 60px.
> Logos with a solid background should include 6px minimum padding
> around the graphic.

Comment: My problem was in the context of articles. Independent publishers or organizations validate differently. But in the article context, only what I posted gets validated. Also, the google code examples, don't validate. Also, I am working with microdata which I am not yet 100% how it translates to json. And there are many examples with json but no microdata.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: AMP and non-AMP pages have different property requirements and
> recommendations. [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#non-amp)

#### AMP VS NON-AMP

### AMP (Mandatory publisher logo)

On AMP rich results the logo is Mandatory ("The Indian Express" in this example).

[image]

**AMP article logo guidelines:**
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#logo-guidelines

### NON AMP (Not mandatory publisher logo)

The publisher logo property **is not** mandatory (Although you get this error).

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#non-amp

Non-AMP search results **can** include a headline and an image:
[image]

### Testing tool error

Anyway, for now, to avoid testing tool error.
If you comment the logo microdata code you get an error:
[image]

Uncomment (add publisher). Fix this issue.

**Basic Microdata outline:**

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h1 itemprop="headline">Hello article</h1>
    <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    <!-- article image -->
    <img itemprop="image" src="article.jpg" alt="Article image"/>
    <!-- datePublished/dateModified -->
    Published at: <span itemprop="datePublished">01/07/2020</span>
    Last modify: <span itemprop="dateModified">08/07/2020</span>
    <!-- publisher -->
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" >
        <span itemprop="name">Google</span>      
        <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <img  itemprop="url" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" alt="publisher" />
        </div>
        <a itemprop="url" href="www.publisher.com" />publisher url</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

[image]

Related:
https://schema.org/logo

Answer (score 0):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Article Name</h1>
    <h1 itemprop="author">Author Name</h1>
    <span itemprop="datePublished">22 Aug 2020</span>
    <span itemprop="dateModified">22 Aug 2020</span>
    <span itemprop="headline">some headline</span>
    <a itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="xxx.html" >#</a>
    <img itemprop="image" src="logo.png" >
  
    <p>Published by 
    <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" >
          <span itemprop="name">Publisher Name</span>

          <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" >
              <a href="alice.html" itemprop="url">Alice Jones</a>

              <!-- or invisible to user
              <link itemprop="url" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye" />
              -->

          </span>
    </span>  
</div>
```

Comment: One HTML mistake in your code ==> ImageObject = An image file `img` (Your markup missing image file).